# laravel eloquent ORM Joint multiple table without Foreign key And Multiple model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables. One is user and the other is category, I have written this Eloquent ORM query to retrieves data from category

```
$category = Category::where(['status'=>'active'])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```

In category table here has a field called `user_id`. I want to join the user table and want to retrieve the user name where category table `'user_id' == user table 'id'`.

How can I do this in Laravel eloquent ORM without Foreign key And Multiple models.

Comment: I don't know who voted this question as Opinion-based. But this question should not be opinion-based

Comment: You can define a relation in your category model and specify `user_id` as the mapping attribute to load user with category